# I'm having an error with Identifying if a record is valid

Tags: c#, sql-server

This code is supposed to identify if the record is not existing it will give you  the message "Room is invalid!". But when I tried to run the program it would give me the message several times even though the record is already in the database.

```
 con.Open();
 cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select Room_Name From Rooms", con);
 rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (rdr.Read())
 {
     roomname = rdr["Room_Name"].ToString();
     if (txtRoom.Text != roomname)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Room is invalid.");
         txtRoom.Focus();
     }                       
 }
 rdr.Close();
 con.Close();
```

Comment: Debug and use [breakpoints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-TS8SDUmMY) and check the value of `roomname` and `txtRoom.Text`

Comment: You have got to be kidding.  It loops thru EVERY room.   Many rooms are not valid.  I bet you don't get the message when it gets to the room.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading every record in the database and showing an error on the first invalid match. Filter to your query and use an if instead of a loop

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select Room_Name From Rooms where room_name = @roomName", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@roomName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = txtRoom.Text;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rdr.Read())
{
     roomname = rdr["Room_Name"].ToString();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Room is invalid.");
    txtRoom.Focus();
}
rdr.Close();
con.Close();
```

Also, as an aside, wrap the DB stuff in using statements so resources are properly disposed of.

Comment: I would add something to the effect of not selecting everything and adding a WHERE clause to the query, then checking if any rows are returned.

Comment: @TiesonT. I've added a note to my post to point out this is the prefered option

Comment: You have got to be kidding.  So if the first room is not the correct you exit.

Comment: @garryp Add a LOWER() around both the field name and the query parameter, to make the search case-insensitive (just a suggestion).

Comment: I think it will probably be case insensitive by default if it is SQL Server.

Comment: How about Select  count(*)  From Rooms where Room_Name =  txtRoom.Text

Comment: Maybe he's using that "roomname" somewhere else, and I don't want to encourage him to put a textbox value directly into a query (SQL injection attack).

Comment: Still won't work as you don't add the parameter value. Please vote this down.